# Flutter how to check for null values in api response Json when parsing it to dart class, below is my dart class

Tags: flutter, dart

for the calls where the `image` object is null is get this error below,

```
datatype 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

but for the call where all the 'IMAGE' data is available, I don't get any error.

actually, for some user calls the JSON returned has no `image` object and that's the actual cause of the error, in my future builder `snapshot.hasdata` is equal to `false` meaning the JSON did not serialize
so how can I make my dart class check for null `image` object value without getting the error above, below is my dart class modal.

````
class Test {
  Test({
    required this.debug,
    required this.devide,
    required this.image,
  });
  late final String debug;
  late final String devide;
  late final Image image;
  
  Test.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    debug = json['debug'];
    devide = json['devide'];
    image = Image.fromJson(json['image']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['debug'] = debug;
    _data['devide'] = devide;
    _data['image'] = image.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Image {
  Image({
    required this.src,
    required this.name,
    required this.hOffset,
    required this.vOffset,
    required this.alignment,
  });
  late final String src;
  late final String name;
  late final int hOffset;
  late final int vOffset;
  late final String alignment;
  
  Image.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    src = json['src'];
    name = json['name'];
    hOffset = json['hOffset'];
    vOffset = json['vOffset'];
    alignment = json['alignment'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['src'] = src;
    _data['name'] = name;
    _data['hOffset'] = hOffset;
    _data['vOffset'] = vOffset;
    _data['alignment'] = alignment;
    return _data;
  }
}

```
````

Comment: Why don't you check if the response is `null` before serializing it ?

Answer (score 1):

In model you can define values like
`paidByNum = json['paidByNum'] ?? defaultValue;`

For example if paidByNum is of type int then
`paidByNum = json['paidByNum'] ?? 0;`

For string
`paidByNum = json['paidByNum'] ?? "";`

This will replace the null value with default value.

Comment: Is there any other way or interceptor which check response value and assigned some value by default, instead of checking each value?

Answer (score 1):

simply do a null check and assign a default or null

`_data['id'] = id == null ? null : id;`

PS: typed code is more welcome than screenshots